# Are there any known examples of animals with air-conditioner type cooling?

Tags: zoology

Sweating is often poor at cooling, particularly on humans and animals with a lot of hair or fur because it collects on clothes and other coverings, trapping heat in while promoting the growth of potentially pathogenic bacteria. Additionally, sweating leaks out important electrolytes and water.

With that in mind, are there any known examples of animals that mimic an air conditioner's heat pump? In particular, consider a special channel where blood (or even better: a specialized cooling fluid) is pressurized (almost similar to inflammation) and pumped through a fin, then depressurized on the way out.